# android programming can httpurlconnection be used in webroot

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

I was wondering can you connect android to the webroot of your project in order to communicate with MySQL or can this only be done by a web url? For instance all examples I have seen so for is off android communicating with MySQL by using a URL such as

```
  URL url = new URL("www.mysite.net/connect.php");
                HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
```

But would it be possible to do something like this

```
      URL url = new URL("mysite/webroot/connect.php");
                HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
```

The reason being is that I do not have a website and all the examples of connecting to the databases use a valid URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`HttpURLConnection` does exactly what it's name implies:

- Connect to a URL, which gives us the IP address to connect to
- Use HTTP protocol to communicate with server

First of all, I think what you're trying to achieve is a local database, a database that resides on the android phone itself. In which case, `HttpURLConnection` is completely unrelated :)

There are plenty of tutorials and references for connecting to a local database, you should start here: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html

However, if you are trying to connect to a remote database (a database that is living within the internet, and not the phone), that's a very complex beast you are wishing to tackle :P  And is *also* unrelated to `HttpURLConnection`, as MySQL has it's own communication protocol that is not HTTP. It is very much recommended that you access that database via something like a RESTful API, which usually translates to a website.

Good luck